# Setting a CSS gradient in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I've been trying to set a gradient with javascript so that it has a mouse over effect, but I've had no luck and cannot get it to work, here is my javascript.

```
function mouseOVER(x)
{
x.backgroundImage="-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #F7F7F7), color-stop(1, #FFFFFF));";
}

function mouseOFF(x)
{
x.backgroundImage="-webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #F7F7F7), color-stop(1, #BABABA));";

}​
```

I've been using jsFiddle to test things, so [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fluffy977/ZauwA/) is mine for this.

Comment: If you want mouseOver style change, try to use CSS `:hover` pseudoclass and there add gradient background

Comment: Tamlyn, I also intended for it to change the text, but I've made that work in javascript, so should the text and gradient be done separately?

Comment: i'd also suggest you to use css :hover and only if it is necessary (and only then) use jquery 1.8 for that case because it adds prefixes for different browsers since 1.8 for css3 features ;)

Comment: @GeorgeSumpster Use CSS always when posible, bacause you can have adventages of browser GPU rendering. It much faster than DOM manipulating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try somethink like this, with CSS only

**CSS**

```
#home{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #F7F7F7), color-stop(1, #BABABA));
    width:100px;
    height:45px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:10px;
    position:relative;
    top:15px;
    left:15px;
}
#home:hover{
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #F7F7F7), color-stop(1, #FFFFFF));
}
#homenav{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000000;
    position:relative;
    top:12.5px;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/enve/ZauwA/11/

---

To change your text on mouseover use this code

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div id="home">
    <a href="home.html" id="homenav" onmouseover="changeText()" onmouseout="returnText()">HOME</a>
    </div>
</nav>​

<script>
function changeText()
{
document.getElementById("homenav").innerHTML='Welcome'
}
function returnText()
{
document.getElementById("homenav").innerHTML='Home'
}
</script>
```

FULL DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/enve/ZauwA/19/

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery this works:

```
$('#block').css({
    background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000))" 
});
```

You also need to apply the styles for other non-webkit browsers.

Dont know why youre Fiddle doesnt work. The Console tells me that youre functions are not defined.

Why are you trying to do this? If not necessary i would definteley suggest the CSS-way mentioned above.

Comment: I was also going to have the text change, bur I guess having them separate also works. I need to figure out my functions being defined, I have trouble with them all the time v.v

Comment: It seems like you have to declare the functions before they're called. You could add them in a <script>-Tag into the header.

Comment: +1, [there is no need for jQuery though](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11943766/1081234)

Answer (score 1):

No need to use jQuery, vanilla JS is fine. You're simply missing a correct `style` property reference:

```
x.backgroundImage='...'; //no such property
x.style.backgroundImage='...'; //works correctly
```

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/fL2Cq/) (requires a webkit browser obviously)

That being said, you should really use pure CSS and rely on `:hover` [dynamic pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes):

```
#home {/*gradient 1*/}
#home:hover {/*gradient 2*/}
```

Comment: +1 for the correct solution! Was not sure about the right JavaScript Syntax for backgroundImage as i forgot most of it using jQuery so much :P

Answer (score 0):

Would you be open for a pure CSS solution?

if so, add this:

```
#homenav:hover{
    -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #F7F7F7), color-stop(1, #FFFFFF));
}
```

​

Comment: You probably should also provide a solution in JS, to answer the OP. Frankly, I don't even know what the problem is.

Comment: Apparently, he accepted a pure CSS answer by Enve, so that wasn't the case.

Comment: Yeah, I was not aware that CSS was the best option, thank you though Rodnik.